# django admin: keeping selected items on different page in changelist view

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin, django-views

a question about admin: in the [changelist page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#customize-the-admin-change-list), is it possible to keep the selected items of a page while going to another page and returning to it.

I mean:

1. I'm on the page 1;
2. I select some items;
3. then i go to page 2;
4. I select other items;
5. I return to page 1;
6. my previous selection is lost.

Is it possible to keep that selection somewhere (cookie, session,...)?

thanks,
Luke

Answer (score 1):

I think, that you may use jquery and cookie manipulation in admin:

- prepare js file with some piece of code to handle click when selecting items and store selected values as array in cookie (use jquery.cookie.js plugin, it is really good stuff); the core of js file may be:

  (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function($) {
          //js code
      });
  })(django.jQuery);
- point js file in your admin.py:

  class SomenameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      class Media:
          js = ("/static/javascript/test.js",)

  admin.site.register(Somename, SomenameAdmin)